# Why is Box2D body's line, distorted , unclear and not straight when rendered using WebGL?

Tags: javascript, box2d, webgl

I'm using Box2DWeb with javascript and WebGL.

My bodies' dimensions are around 1.0 and the ground is around 5.0 in Box2D.
I simply draw them using WebGL using **translate** and **rotate** (using values obtained from **GetPosition()** and **GetAngle()** function). I use the same values I get from those functions.
i.e., I use values around 1.0 to draw the objects and around 5.0 for the ground.

The issue is when rotation occurs, (like when 2 bodies collide), the bodies rotate and translate until equilibrium and the final position drawn is **unclear**. The lines are not straight even when the object is simply lying on the ground.
Without rotation, the bodies look just fine.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPv8z.png) is an image:

As you can see some side and bottom lines are not straight. They appear distorted.
Why could this be happening?

To summarize, I **step** the world, **store** changed positions and angles somewhere, and using **WebGL** I translate to the point and rotate using WebGL calls and draw the body on the screen.

**[EDIT]**
The angle while resting down finally for the bigger object was : -3.1379659302514917 ! It didn't go down to a complete `-PI` . Maybe thats why it is seen that way. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Do the bodies otherwise behave correctly? What are the exact values you get for GetAngle in that situation?

Comment: The bodies behave pretty realistically.
The angle while resting down finally for the bigger object was :  -3.1379659302514917 ! It didn't go down to a complete -PI . Maybe thats why it is seen that way. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it happened because I was using perspective projection and not orthographic projection to draw 2D stuff.

Also I had to keep the images in 0.5 m to 5 m range and use a scale of 30.0 to convert between screen pixels and Box2D meters.

Answer (score 1):

It is inevitable that a generic physics engine will produce inexact results. You may be able to tune it to come to a closer approximation by setting tighter thresholds for stopping the simulation of nearly stationary bodies (apparently Box2D calls this “sleeping”).

You can also make it less obvious on-screen by using antialiased graphics, so that the slight rotation does not create a one-pixel kink in the line but a more gradual slope.

You could also tweak the rotation value under the assumption that being close to a multiple π/2 is actually exact, but that would create a noticeable glitch in a tumbling body.

Comment: There are loads of Box2D demos/apps on the web. They are not glitchy like mine. Do you know which of those approaches you mentioned is generally used by other developers?

Comment: And about the 1st approach, can you please explain, what it means to set a "tighter threshold" for stopping simulation of nearly stationary bodies? Even if I were to find out that a body is resting, I can't be sure it is resting on a flat surface. There may actually be a slight 0.01 radian incline. I failed to see how that would help. I mean, how correct would it be approximate a body's angle just because it is resting? That may produce wrong results, just the same way as your 3rd approach.

AM I totally missing something?

Comment: It's not that you should look for unmoving bodies — it's that Box2D will already be doing that. If you change it to simulate for longer by setting a smaller velocity threshold, they may settle down flatter. I've never used Box2D in particular, so I can't help further.